# How to get Excel cell color in VB.net?

Tags: excel-2010, vb.net-2010

I want to read the color of an Excel cell using VB.net. I have used the `xlctsSheet.Cells(Row, Col).style.interior.color` property but it just gives me some number.

What property do I need to use to get color of a cell?

Answer (score 0):

The number you are seeing **IS** the color.  Here are some typical *ColorIndex* equivalents:

[image]

Comment: i am not able to see the image attached. kindly send it again.

Comment: I am writing this but i am getting colorindex as 0:               sheet.Cells.Range("B1: B1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 102)
 sheet.Cells.Range("B1").Interior.Color = colorindex